# Split and select text between brackets

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file with content like below but I'm only interested on some information

```
[2018-01-06 18:52:00,376] INFO [workflow@xxx] - [com.app.gateway] size of [1] message
[2018-01-06 18:54:00,188] INFO [workflow@xxx] - [com.app.gateway] size of [3] message
[2018-01-06 18:55:00,140] INFO [workflow@xxx] - [com.app.gateway] size of [5] message
```

I want to clean it up and output the following:

```
[2018-01-06 18:52:00]  [1]
[2018-01-06 18:54:00]  [3]
[2018-01-06 18:55:00]  [5]
```

I'm thinking of using split but how can I split between brackets?

Thank you!

Comment: Just split at spaces and put the first 2 pieces back together afterwards?

Comment: If you need a regex, you can set the multiline flag and match [`^(\[[0-9 :,-]+]).*(\[[0-9 :,-]+]).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/DUifEA/2/) and replace it with `$1 $2` as shown [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/DUifEA/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sample inputs you have provided, it seems that you want the data in square brackets containing only numbers/timestamps. *This solution will work only if this assumption is right throughout your file.*

Here is a regex that you can try:

```
^(\[[0-9 :,-]+]).*(\[[0-9 :,-]+]).*$
```

Replace each match with `$1 $2`

[Click for Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DUifEA/2/)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(\[[0-9 :,-]+])` - matches `[` followed by 1+ occurrences of (either a digit or a `:` or a `,` or a `-` or a space) followed by a `]` and capture it as Group 1
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character greedily
- `(\[[0-9 :,-]+])` - matches `[` followed by 1+ occurrences of (either a digit or a `:` or a `,` or a `-` or a space) followed by a `]` and capture it as Group 2
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character greedily
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

**Code:**

```
$var= "[2018-01-06 18:52:00,376] INFO [workflow@xxx] - [com.app.gateway] size of [1] message" 
$var = $var-replace "^(\[[0-9 :,-]+]).*(\[[0-9 :,-]+]).*$",'$1 $2'
$var
```

[Click for Code Demo](https://tio.run/##Zcy9CsIwFEDh3ae4lED9aUpSsdZCwUlw0QeIEUK5rWJKQiKm@vKRujodOMNnTUDnb6g1bY3DGMlLuQYSUTBeUcYpK4FX9aaoGcvW21LC8XQ4gwjGPTptwn4cRwkURGuGXFmb9@qJQb0l@PsHwXQguIQBvVc9JjCbeGhgCnVotWoRkuv8IgSjO6gzKldykS//BkmylHAgRfojYvwC)

Comment: Wow this great! Still don't understand Regex but thank you for the solution and explanation!