# Regex for splitting bracketed text "[ab][ij][yz]" into a list of ["[ab]", "[ij]", "[yz]"]

Tags: regex

As the title says, I am trying to split bracketed text, for example "[ab][ij][yz]" into a list, like {"[ab]", "[ij]", "[yz]"} or {"ab", "ij", "yz"}.  I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133138/split-and-select-text-between-brackets), and something similar would work, but the case there is more specific and I just need a simpler and more general regex.

Comment: You can try that: ``[^[\]]+``. See https://regex101.com/r/SmSbXy/1

Comment: @Cubix48 Thanks for your answer, but I'm using Java and the pattern doesn't work in java regex

Comment: In Java you also need to escape the ``[``: ``[^\[\]]+``.

Comment: List? You mean `["ab", "ij", "yz"]` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
[^\[\]]+
```

Each character different from `[` or `]` is matched as many times as possible, the matches are therefore between each square brackets.

See the online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/8ojHgG/1).

---

- `[^]`: Match a single character not present in the list.

  - `\[`: Matches `[`.
  - `\]`: Matches `]`.
- `+`: Matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.

---

In java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\[\\]]+");
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher("[ab][ij][yz]");
        
        ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            allMatches.add(m.group(0));
        }
        System.out.println(allMatches);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example with the wrapping `[` `]`

```
/\[[^\]]+\]/g
```

```js
console.log(
  "[ab][ij][yz]".match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g)
);
```

https://regex101.com/r/IljP6k/3

---

Example *without* the wrapping `[` `]` using Positive lookbehind `(?<=)`

```
/(?<=\[)[^\]]+/g
```

```js
console.log(
  "[ab][ij][yz]".match(/(?<=\[)[^\]]+/g)
);
```

https://regex101.com/r/IljP6k/2